# Any DB that supports queries over long bitfields?

Tags: database

Assume I want to query a bit field, is there any database that allows queries over long strings of bitfields?

In example: `query = 0011XXXXXX`.

The bitfield have the first 2 values to 0, the second 2 values to 1, and any other value can be anything.

Comment: Some DBMS support `LIKE` condition over numeric fields

Comment: You mean like `XOR` and similar operators? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-bitstring.html

Comment: oh yeah thanks. Didn't expected to have it in SQL :O

Comment: Bear in mind that *by default*, you should be storing *separate* values (of the same "type") in *separate* rows. Bitpacking doesn't really fit with normalisation, indexing, etc. (Assuming by database you're talking relational)

Comment: Just a mean to store a vast amount of options in one place. Instead of writing complex queryies. Just query the bitfields